# How to send JSON from postman for a custom VO

Tags: json, spring, get, postman, spring-restcontroller

What is the format of JSON that I should be sending from Postman to correctly map it to my rest controller.

```
TfundsVO :
BigDecimal accountNum
String accountName
BigDecimal accountBal



@GetMapping("/")
public ResponseEntity<Object> getFunds(@RequestBody TfundsVO tfundsVO) {
    System.out.println(tfundsVO.getAccountNum());
}
```

Sample JSON used:

```
{
    "tfundsVO": [
     {
        "accountName": "Sam"
     } 
  ]
}
```

When I tried the above JSON from Postman, call goes to the getFunds method, however all the values in TfundsVO are NULL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just send the payload without an array

```
{ "account name": "test" }
```

And please add an application/json header as a content-type